# Adjusting the width of a tcolorbox to its content?

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to embed `tikzcircuit`s in `tcolorbox`es in a document; I am struggling to find a way of making the box behaving more or less like an `fbox` with respect to the width.

I am solving the problem by  setting the width by hand (see code below), but it would be nice to have a way to tell `tcolorbox` to make a box as wide as needed. Is it possible?

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{common/.style={
        colback=yellow!10,
        colframe=blue!60,
        halign=flush left, leftrule=4mm,
}}
\newtcolorbox{circbox}[3][]{common,
    width=#2\linewidth, title = {#3}, nobeforeafter, 
    #1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circbox}{0.3}{Polarización}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{circbox}
    \begin{circbox}{0.5}{Señal}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm) (1.3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{circbox}

    \bigskip

    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm) (1.3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

which, compiled, led to:

[image: Output of the previous code]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an option called `hbox` which basically does what you want, adjust the width to the content.

[image: hbox]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{common/.style={
        colback=yellow!10,
        colframe=blue!60,
        halign=flush left, leftrule=4mm,
}}
\newtcolorbox{circbox}[2][]{common,
    hbox, title = {#2}, nobeforeafter, 
    #1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circbox}{Polarización}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{circbox}
    \begin{circbox}{Señal}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm) (1.3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{circbox}

    \bigskip

    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1cm) (1.3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```