# how to align and automatically adjust tcolorbox width with tikzpicture inside or title?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, width

I couldn't find a way to make the tcolorbox adjust automatically with the tikzpictures inside or the title (if it's wider). I also want them to appear on the **same line**.

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}




\newtcolorbox{blueboxb}[1]{hbox,center title, colback=pink!20, 
 colframe=blue!20,fonttitle=\bfseries,title={#1}}
\newtcolorbox{blueboxs}[1]{hbox,center title, colback=pink!20, 
 colframe=blue!20,fonttitle=\bfseries,title={#1}}
\newtcolorbox{orangebox}[1]{colback=pink!20,colframe=orange!40,fonttitle=\bfseries,
 title={#1}}

 \begin{blueboxb}{\color{black}{Droites parallèles}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 %1
 \begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
\draw[green!50!blue] (2,1) -- (4.5,2.5) node [right] {$\Delta$};
\draw[red!80,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] (2,1) -- (4.5,2.5) node [right] 
{$\Delta^{\prime}$};
\end{scope}

%2
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
\draw[red!80] (2,2.5) -- (5.5,1.5);
\draw[green!50!blue,dashed,thick] (2,2.5) -- (5.5,1.5) node [midway,above right] 
{$\Delta=\Delta^{\prime}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{blueboxb}
\begin{blueboxs}{\color{black}{Droites Confondues}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
 \draw[red!80] (2,2.5) -- (4.5,1) node [right] {$\Delta$};
 \draw[green!50!blue] (2,1) -- (4.5,2.5) node [right] {$\Delta^{\prime}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{blueboxs}
 \begin{orangebox}{\color{black}{Droites Confondues}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
 \draw[thick,red!80] (2.5,4.5) node[black,right] {$\Delta^{\prime}$} -- (5,-0.5);
 \fill[pink!20] (4,0.1) rectangle (4.9,2);
 \draw[red!80,dashed] (2.5,4.5) -- (5,-0.5);
 \draw[green!50!blue] (0.5,0.4) node [right,black] {$\Delta$} -- (3,2.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{orangebox}



\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445992/adjusting-the-width-of-a-tcolorbox-to-its-content help?

Comment: Thank you @Rmano it does help. Is there a way to adjust with the title length when it is wider than the content? I know this is not what I asked in the beginning.
Also how to put the 3 on the same line?

Comment: I do not think that there is an option for taking into account the tile length, although you can always add some phantom line as width as the title in the boxes. To put three of them, if they fit (including the spaces between) they just will go on the same line.

Comment: @Rmano they fit, or at least 2 of them fit, but I have one in each line (so 3 lines)

Comment: ...I'm not on the computer now, I'll check tomorrow...

Comment: If all your boxes will contain `tikzpictures` you can use a `tikz upper` option and save declaring `begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` into every box. And if you add `coltitle=black` you can avoid fixing the title color for all of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the linked answer (a bit hidden, but...)

1. The `hbox` keyword makes the box the (horizontal) size of the content, and
2. the `nobeforeafter` switch suppresses the normal spacing that `tcolorbox` issues before and after the box (look for it in the manual).

Adding this option, and showing the frame of the page, you have:

[image: boxes]

Notice the `\parident` at the start of the first line, and the fact that you do not have `hbox` nor `nobeforeafter` on the `orangebox, so it starts with something similar to` \par\noindent`.

Code for this:

```latex
documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{blueboxb}[1]{hbox,center title, colback=pink!20, 
 colframe=blue!20,fonttitle=\bfseries,title={#1},nobeforeafter}
\newtcolorbox{blueboxs}[1]{hbox,center title, colback=pink!20, 
 colframe=blue!20,fonttitle=\bfseries,title={#1},nobeforeafter}
\newtcolorbox{orangebox}[1]{colback=pink!20,colframe=orange!40,fonttitle=\bfseries, title={#1}}

 \begin{blueboxb}{\color{black}{Droites parallèles}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 %1
 \begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
\draw[green!50!blue] (2,1) -- (4.5,2.5) node [right] {$\Delta$};
\draw[red!80,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] (2,1) -- (4.5,2.5) node [right] 
{$\Delta^{\prime}$};
\end{scope}
%2
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
\draw[red!80] (2,2.5) -- (5.5,1.5);
\draw[green!50!blue,dashed,thick] (2,2.5) -- (5.5,1.5) node [midway,above right] 
{$\Delta=\Delta^{\prime}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{blueboxb}
\begin{blueboxs}{\color{black}{Droites Confondues}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
 \draw[red!80] (2,2.5) -- (4.5,1) node [right] {$\Delta$};
 \draw[green!50!blue] (2,1) -- (4.5,2.5) node [right] {$\Delta^{\prime}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{blueboxs}
 \begin{orangebox}{\color{black}{Droites Confondues}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (7,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
 \draw[thick,red!80] (2.5,4.5) node[black,right] {$\Delta^{\prime}$} -- (5,-0.5);
 \fill[pink!20] (4,0.1) rectangle (4.9,2);
 \draw[red!80,dashed] (2.5,4.5) -- (5,-0.5);
 \draw[green!50!blue] (0.5,0.4) node [right,black] {$\Delta$} -- (3,2.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{orangebox}
\end{document}
```

If you add `hbox` and `nobeforeafter` to the `orangebox`, you'll have:

[image: overfull boxes]

...because they do not fit in a line.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Rmano. I found another trick to align them, it's to put them in minipages (also a `hspace` to force them to fit on a line). Thanks again for your helps!